# Object gets stored in session, but while retrieving it is null

Tags: c#

On page load I am populating my own object, storing in session & it is getting stored,
When I am debugging i can see that object is stored in session, But When I am reading that session variable.. it is null,

Surprizingly I am able to use other session variables,

Howerver I am able to get the session variable when my sessionstate = "InProc"... and I get it null when sessionstate='StateServer' or sessionstate='SQLServer'

I've kept session TimeOut="20",
On the page I've added EnableSessionState="True"

Please help,
- Prashant C

Comment: Could you post your code? If you can use other session variables, what are you doing differently?

Comment: marking your classes as Serializable and implementing IDeserializationCallback 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your type implement `ISerializable` (directly or indirectly, perhaps via inheritance)? The biggest difference between in-proc and the rest is that in-proc doesn't serialize, so serialization is the first thing to look at.

It does sound very odd, though - if it was "off", I would expect to get either an exception or an uninitialised object - not a null. Maybe a silly question, but the incoming request definitely has all the right headers/cookies? i.e. it still knows which session it is in?

To explain, if your type **neither** implements `ISerializable` **nor** has `[Serializable]` I would expect an exception; you've added `[Serializable]`, but the fact that it didn't already error makes me think there is some `ISerializable` in the mix.

Comment: Hi all, The issue is solved...

I did a silly mistake.. I had forgot to add [serializable] to class definitions  of data members contained in my wrapper class..

[seriablizable]

class class_first

{

...

class second = new class_second();

...

}


I had made only class_first as [serializable]  and not class_second...

I was not finiding any errors because of an error handling module..

But I hope this helps to all others


I really appreciate your time and help,

Cheers  !!

- Prashant C

Answer (score 1):

sessionstate='StateServer' or sessionstate='SQLServer' requires that your Objects are serializable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I've added.. 

[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
   ...
}

still the same effect... is there any other way to do it ?